# Getting "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." while inspecting camunda cockpit version 7.14.0

Tags: camunda, camunda-plugin

We recently upgraded to version 7.14.0 of camunda-webapp-webjar. After this upgrade the css for cockpit stopped loading. I found there were changes done to the way we write / manage plugin in 7.14.0 ( "A Reworked Cockpit Plugin System"  https://camunda.com/blog/2020/10/camunda-bpm-runtime-7-14-0-released/)

When I do inspect on cockpit page I see below

```
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
```

Comment: Checked your browser settings? Is script allowed?

Comment: Thanks @JanGalinski for your comment. This helped https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.14/update/minor/713-to-714/#changes-to-the-cockpit-config-file. I made necessary changes in cockpit config.js and it worked.